# Script para criação de tabelas no mySQL usando Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Estou pretendendo criar um *script* para criar tabelas no *mySQL* utilizando *Python 3* para cadastrar usuários, cada tabela terá como nome o CPF da pessoa, porém está acontecendo um erro de *syntax (1064)* que não consegui identificar. **Todos as variáveis são do tipo string**

O script que tenho até o momento é:

```
import mysql.connector
Database = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    database='datacenter'
)
def cadastra_db(nome,cpf,email,cargo,setor):
    cursor = Database.cursor()
    comando_createtable = f"CREATE TABLE {cpf}(\nid INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\nnome VARCHAR(50),\ncargo VARCHAR(50),\nsetor VARCHAR(50),\nemail VARCHAR(50),\ncpf VARCHAR(50),\nPRIMARY KEY(id)\n);"
    print(comando_createtable)
    cursor.execute(comando_createtable)
    Database.commit()
```

No `print(comando_creatable)` a saída é :

```
CREATE TABLE 123(
id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(50),
cargo VARCHAR(50),
setor VARCHAR(50),
email VARCHAR(50),
cpf VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Tendo como base a saida do print eu não sei oque está acontecendo para que o comando não de certo.

Comment: Acredito que o nome da tabela tenha que estar entre aspas simples. Isso porque o nome possui apenas números.

Comment: @PauloMarques não é esse o problema todas as variáveis são do tipo string, mesmo o CPF tendo simbolos numéricos ele é uma string

Comment: estou falando do nome da tabela mesmo. Talvez seja `CREATE TABLE '123' (...`

Comment: Faz sentido o que o Paulo Marques ta falando. Ao chamar um comando SQL via IDE usamos aspas diferentes pra passar _Strings_ para o banco. No seu caso deve se fazer isso na variavel _cpf_. Seu comando ficaria: ***f"CREATE TABLE '{cpf}'(\nid INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\nnome VARCHAR(50),\ncargo VARCHAR(50),\nsetor VARCHAR(50),\nemail VARCHAR(50),\ncpf VARCHAR(50),\nPRIMARY KEY(id)\n);"***

Comment: O certo é usar o backtick (`) em volta no numero. Mas o nome da tabela é o cpf da pessoa? Isso não faz muito sentido pra mim.

Comment: @AlexCiuffa corretíssimo a sua resposta o uso do backtick arrumou o meu problema, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Só pra fazer algum sentido o CPF dá pessoa irá servir como um identificador pois cada colaborador terá sua tabela exclusiva.